# how to make php mb_str_ireplace()

Tags: php, string, replace

How to do something like this:

`mb_str_ireplace($search,$replace,$subject,"UTF-8");`

This function does not exist in PHP, but I need to have got case insensitive and  UTF-8 compatible function.

for example:
I want to change $search -> $replace:

```
GŁOŚNIKI -> speakers;
Głośniki -> speakers;
głośniki -> speakers;
gŁoŚniki -> speakers;
```

EDIT:

deceze's answer

`$text = preg_replace('/głośniki/ui', 'speakers', $text);`

is good for previous case. But I have got one more problem.

I want to change all previous versions of `"głośniki"` to `<speakers>głośniki</speakers>`

```
GŁOŚNIKI -> <speakers>głośniki</speakers>;
Głośniki -> <speakers>głośniki</speakers>;
głośniki -> <speakers>głośniki</speakers>;
gŁoŚniki -> <speakers>głośniki</speakers>;
```

I mean something like this:

```
mb_str_ireplace(
    $search,
    $openTag.$replace.$closeTag,
    $subject,
    "UTF-8"
);
```

Comment: According to your edit, just replace with `<speakers>głośniki</speakers>`?

Comment: Głośniki is not const word. foreach($words as $word){...$search=$word; $replace=mb_strtolower($word,"UTF-8");)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your edit you want deceze's method to be useable with dynamic variables without declaring them all. This is super simple with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain;');

$string = 'I have a string with a gŁoŚniki word. Pretty interesting';
$word = 'Głośniki';

$string = preg_replace_callback('/(' . preg_quote($word, '/') . ')/ui', function($match) {
    return '<speakers>' . mb_strtolower($match[1], 'UTF-8') . '</speakers>';
}, $string);

var_dump($string);
```

**Output**:

```
string(79) "I have a string with a <speakers>głośniki</speakers> word. Pretty interesting"
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pof89b)

Please note that I've used `preg_quote($word, '/')` to make sure that we escape any character that might mess with the regex (eg. `?`, `+`, `.` etc.)

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = preg_replace('/głośniki/ui', 'speakers', $text);
```

The `u` flag is for UTF-8 processing, the `i` for case insensitivity.

Comment: Note for future users: This accounts for the text to be in UTF-8 (which also seems to be what OP was using for his `mb_str_ireplace` test).

Comment: how without regular expressions to solve this problem y?

Provided that the Register of characters in the line of a pointer can not be changed (!).